# pass value of reactiveValue into observeEvent with if statement to create conditional tabs in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to create dynamic tabs in a shiny app
when a user enters an api token, that is used for api call to generate a table

If the api call is successful, I would like to show tabs 1 and 2
However, if the api call is NOT successful or shows an ERROR, i would like to hide the tabs 1 and 2

I have a basic reprex below, which does not seem to work.

How do I pass the value of a reactiveVal into an if statement? Specifically, if the reactiveValue does not yet exists, how do I check for this within an if statement? some version of validate(need()) perhaps?

Thank you for the help

```
library(shiny)



ui <- function() {
  fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel("mytabs", 
          type = "tabs", 
          
          tabPanel("home", 
                   
                   textInput("enterval", label = "enterval"
                             
                   )
          ), 
          tabPanel("tab1"), 
          tabPanel("tab2")
          
  )
)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

  vals <- reactiveValues(

    a = NULL

  )

  vals$a <- eventReactive(input$enterval, {

# in reality, an api call creates an object (dataframe) when input$enterval is filled with a correct token
return(input$enterval)

  })

  observeEvent(input$enterval, {

if(is.null(vals$a()) # OR ERROR IS RETURNED FROM API CALL (vals$a) (possible to use validate(need()) here?)
   
   ) {
  
  hideTab(inputId = "mytabs", target = "tab1")
  hideTab(inputId = "mytabs", target = "tab2")
  
  
} else {
  
  showTab(inputId = "mytabs", target = "tab1")
  showTab(inputId = "mytabs", target = "tab2")
  
  
    }

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few modifications:

1. use explicitely the `id` argument for `tabsetPanel`
2. modify `vals` inside an `observeEvent`
3. compare `vals$a` to `""` instead of using `is.null` because `vals$a` in your toy example a string (you could use `nrow(df)>0` for a dataframe)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- function() {
  fluidPage(tabsetPanel(id = "mytabs",
                        type = "tabs",
                        tabPanel("home",textInput("enterval", label = "enterval")),
                        tabPanel("tab1"),
                        tabPanel("tab2"))
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  vals <- reactiveValues( a = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$enterval, {

    # in reality, an api call creates an object (dataframe) when input$enterval is filled with a correct token
    vals$a <- input$enterval

  })

  observeEvent(input$enterval, {

    if(vals$a =="" ) {

      hideTab(inputId = "mytabs", target = "tab1")
      hideTab(inputId = "mytabs", target = "tab2")

    } else {

      showTab(inputId = "mytabs", target = "tab1")
      showTab(inputId = "mytabs", target = "tab2")

    }

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]